# Using seriatim and respectively in a sentence?

Tags: sentence

Folks, i need to know if we can use *seriatim* and *respective* in a sentence like this:

*The speakers in seriatim thanked Company A and Company B respectively to support the event.*

What i want to say is that Mr. Speaker A is grateful to Company A and Mr. Speaker B is grateful to Company B. The names of the speakers are shown on the top of the document and not in the footnote where i am documenting the acknowledgement.

Comment: Simply _Mr. A and B thank Company A and B, respectively._ Mind the plural verb. It will convey your meaning, and you avoid using the superfluous _in seriatim_ which is, at best, an obscure expression for most people.

Comment: Thanks oerkelens for helping out. I have further modified the question.

Comment: 'In turn' is probably better than 'in seriatim'. It has pretty much the same meaning in your context and is much more widely understood. I had to look up the definition of 'seriatim' as it was completely unknown to me.